# Get version number/name of the MvxApplication

Tags: mvvmcross

Is there a way to get version number and version name in MvxApplication automaticaly or we have to code it for each platform?

Answer (score 4):

I don't see an existing plugin for getting cross-platform app version numbers, but it shouldn't be too difficult to write.

Here's how to get the current version number for each platform. I'm sure you can write similar code to get build number and app name.

**Windows Phone**

```c#
public static string GetVersion()
{
    var versionAttribute = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyFileVersionAttribute), true)
        .FirstOrDefault() as AssemblyFileVersionAttribute;

    return versionAttribute != null ? versionAttribute.Version : "";
}
```

**Android**

```c#
public static string GetVersion()
{
    var context = Application.Context;
    var info = context.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(context.PackageName, 0);
    return info.VersionName;
}
```

**iOS**

```c#
public static string GetVersion()
{
    NSObject version = NSBundle.MainBundle.InfoDictionary["CFBundleShortVersionString"];
    return version.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

More detailed android info:

```
public class InfoService : IInfoService
{
    public string DeviceId
    {
        get
        {                
            return Settings.Secure.GetString(Application.Context.ContentResolver, Settings.Secure.AndroidId);
        }
    }

    public string PackageName
    {
        get
        {
            return Application.Context.PackageName;
        }
    }

    public string AppVersionName
    {
        get
        {
            var context = Application.Context;
            var info = context.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(context.PackageName, 0);

            return info.VersionName;
        }
    }

    public int AppVersionCode
    {
        get
        {
            var context = Application.Context;
            var info = context.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(context.PackageName, 0);

            return info.VersionCode;
        }
    }

    public double DeviceScreenWidth
    {
        get
        {
            var context = Application.Context;
            var displayMetrics = context.Resources.DisplayMetrics;

            return displayMetrics.WidthPixels / displayMetrics.Density;
        }
    }

    public double DeviceScreenHeight
    {
        get
        {
            var context = Application.Context;
            var displayMetrics = context.Resources.DisplayMetrics;

            return displayMetrics.HeightPixels / displayMetrics.Density;
        }
    }
}
```